# A verb for having "ability" after not having it. Do we get the ability, gain the ability, ...?

Tags: single-word-requests

> After a while I _______ the ability to understand their costumes.

I want a verb for the above blank.

Acquire, gain, obtain, and a lot of more verbs are used in such cases, but I would like to know the most idiomatic verb.

Comment: How about "enable"?

Comment: 'the ability of understanding' should it not read 'the ability to understand' ?

Answer (score 5):

"Most idiomatic" can be a pretty subjective measure. Instead, let's try looking at the "most popular" verbs.

Although it's not really the right tool for the job, I used NGram to get a list of the most popular verbs that come before "the ability" (using [`*_VERB the ability`](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*_VERB+the+ability&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A_VERB%20the%20ability%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bis_VERB%20the%20ability%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhave_VERB%20the%20ability%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhas_VERB%20the%20ability%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhad_VERB%20the%20ability%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdevelop_VERB%20the%20ability%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas_VERB%20the%20ability%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpossess_VERB%20the%20ability%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blost_VERB%20the%20ability%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bacquire_VERB%20the%20ability%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Black_VERB%20the%20ability%3B%2Cc0)). Ignoring all the irrelevant verbs that would not fit in the context, there were two words that remained. In my opinion as a native speaker they are both very idiomatic here:

- **developed** the ability

  - > to improve your abilities, skills, or knowledge
    >   <sub>[Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/develop)</sub>
- **acquired** the ability

  - > Learn or develop (a skill, habit, or quality)
    >   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/acquire)</sub>

There's nothing wring with using ["gain"](https://www.google.com/search?q="gained+the+ability"&oq="gained+the+ability") or ["got"](https://www.google.com/search?q="just+got+the+ability") in your context either; it's simply less popular.

On a side note, I would use "to" not "of" because it sounds better (again, look at [the popularity in NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=developed+the+ability+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cdeveloped%20the%20ability%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdeveloped%20the%20ability%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdeveloped%20the%20ability%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdeveloped%20the%20ability%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdeveloped%20the%20ability%20for%3B%2Cc0)).